# Merchant account / Payment Gateway or Simply PayPal with PHP?

Tags: php, paypal

I have created a website to both promote my new book, and to accept purchases.  The site utilizes php,css,and js.  The area of payment is not my forte, and consequently, I linked it to my PayPal account to provide users to pay via any type of credit card.  Is it worthwhile to have a merchant account / payment gateway set up, purchase an SSL certificate for secure transactions, etc?  I took what I consider to be the easy road, but unsure if this is the best solution.  PayPal offered a stock image and page to generate JavaScript, so I customized and included it on my site, [www.gofurtherpubs.com](http://www.gofurtherpubs.com/) on the 'get the book' page.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on what level of professionalism you are trying to depict in your site as well as how much time/money you are willing to invest. For example, if you just need a simple way to process transactions and do not care if the user is transferred from your domain to the paypal.com domain, you should stick with the simple solution. If however, you need to keep the users on your website at all times or need to build a more customized shopping cart utility/etc, then perhaps you should upgrade. Check the fees though, I believe upgrading will cost you either a monthly or yearly fee.